# Open visio 2007 document inside windows form using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, integration, visio

I would like to open visio 2007 document inside panel control of  winform application using c#.How can we integrate Visio 2007 with windows form using c#?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the drawing and your redistribution and licensing requirements you could use the Visio ActiveX Control which will allow you manipulate drawings on PCs with Visio installed or the Visio Viewer which allows you read only display of drawings on any PC with the viewer installed.

See

- [Drawing Visio Shapes in the Visio ActiveX Control Using C# and .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/VisioInDotNet12032006222024PM/VisioInDotNet.aspx)
- [About Programming Microsoft Office Visio 2007 Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392798.aspx)